# Swift Facebook SDK Login Button position

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, swift3

I am developing an iOS app using Swift 3 and the Facebook SDK for my Login.
I am still a beginner in iOS development, especially regarding all the UI related stuff (coming from android development)

I am using the `LoginButton` provided by the Facebook SDK, and for now its position is on the center of the screen. I would like to move it to the bottom of my `ViewController`, and if possible to place it in a layout that I would create through the storyboard. (so it will appear exactly where I want)

[Swift Facebook SDK Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login)

I checked the Facebook developper documentation, but I can't find anything providing the properties of that `LoginButton`, and how to change its position. I know that it is also possible to create a custom `LoginButton`, but as I just want to move the button and not change its physical appearance, I don't think it is necessary.

```
let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile , .custom("user_birthday")])

loginButton.center = view.center
loginButton.delegate = self

view.addSubview(loginButton)
```

**EDIT :**

Thanks to lithium's answer, here is what I did :

```
let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile , .custom("user_birthday")])
let newCenter = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.height - 70)
loginButton.center = newCenter
loginButton.delegate = self
view.addSubview(loginButton)
```

That will center the button at the bottom of my viewcontroller, with a margin of 70.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
loginButton.center = view.center
```

you can use any CGPoint instead of view.center here.
for example,

```
let newCenter = CGPoint(15, 20)
loginButton.center = newCenter
```

very lazy approach for putting this button at the bottom of the screen (without using constraints):

```
let screenSize:CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenHeight = screenSize.height //real screen height
//let's suppose we want to have 10 points bottom margin
let newCenterY = screenHeight - loginButton.frame.height - 10
let newCenter = CGPoint(view.center.x, newCenterY)
loginButton.center = newCenter
```

I can't check this right now, but I believe that `loginButton.frame` should work also (as well as any layout constraints in your code).

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to position the default Facebook Login button, all you need to do is the following:

1. Create an empty view and set its constraints

```
@IBOutlet weak var FBLoginView: UIView!
```

2. Attach the view to your controller as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

3. Add the Facebook Login button to your view.

```
let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile, .userFriends, .email]) // If you haven't already done this

// This is where you add your Facebook Login button to the empty view 
self.FBLoginView.addSubview(loginButton)
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: UImageView]

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class RootViewController: UIViewController,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {
    // here your custom UIButton outlet refrence and make sure in storyboard u can give UIButton class name to FBSDKLoginButton.
    @IBOutlet var btnFacebook: FBSDKLoginButton!

    //MARK:- UIView life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.configureFacebook()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    }

    //MARK:- Instance method

    func configureFacebook()
    {
        btnFacebook.readPermissions = \["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"\];
        btnFacebook.delegate = self
        btnFacebook.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
    }

    /**
     Sent to the delegate when the button was used to login.
     - Parameter loginButton: the sender
     - Parameter result: The results of the login
     - Parameter error: The error (if any) from the login
     */
    public func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

        if ((error) != nil) {
            // Process error
            print("Error! : \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return

        } else if result.isCancelled {
            // Handle cancellations
            print("Success! : user cancel login request")
            return
        } else {
            let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: \["fields" : "id, email, name,picture.type(large)"\])
            graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if ((error) != nil) {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                } else {
                    // Do work in app.
                    let dataDict:NSDictionary = result as! NSDictionary
                    if let token = FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString {
                        print("tocken: \(token)")

                        let userDefult = UserDefaults.standard
                        userDefult.setValue(token, forKey: "access_tocken")
                        userDefult.synchronize()
                    }
                    if let user : NSString = dataDict.object(forKey: "name") as! NSString? {
                        print("user: \(user)")
                        self.lblName.text = "Welcome, \(user)"
                    }
                    if let id : NSString = dataDict.object(forKey: "id") as? NSString {
                        print("id: \(id)")
                    }
                    if let email : NSString = (result! as AnyObject).value(forKey: "email") as? NSString {
                        print("email: \(email)")
                    }

                    if let pictureData:NSDictionary = dataDict.object(forKey: "picture") as? NSDictionary{

                        if let data:NSDictionary = pictureData.object(forKey: "data") as? NSDictionary{

                            if let strPictureURL: String = data.object(forKey: "url") as? String{

                                self.ivUserProfileImage.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string: strPictureURL)! as URL)! as Data)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            })
        }
    }

    /**
     Sent to the delegate when the button was used to logout.
     - Parameter loginButton: The button that was clicked.
     */
    public func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!){

        let loginManager: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        loginManager.logOut()
        ivUserProfileImage.image = nil
        lblName.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use your custom UIButton to login with facebook , give custom UIButton class to FBSDKLoginButton and connect outlet. u will get facebook login button as ur UI configuration